# How to subtract using datetime in py

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataset and would like to create a new column that looks 90 days back from the `start_Date` column. I have tried two ways and both cause a typeError.

`df['prior_date'] = df['start_Date'] - 90`

And I tried

`df['prior'] = (df['start_Date')] - dt(days = 90)).strftime('%Y-%m-%D')`

Any suggestions on how to have the created column `prior` work? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas' [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) method:

```
df['prior_date'] = df['start_Date'] - pd.Timedelta(90, "d")
```